# REWRITE ERROR APACHE (WIN)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I recently had to have my OS reinstalled in my development computer and after reinstalling WAMP and my databases, etc I am now getting a 500 error.

THE LOGS:

```
[Wed Aug 14 02:40:02.317999 2013] [core:alert] [pid 3864:tid 856] [client ::1:58187] C:/wamp/www/MonsterFleaMarket/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/
```

My HTACCESS:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ /MonsterFleaMarket/user_home.php?domain=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please Help! This was working fine before the reinstall. What can I do?

Comment: enable this module in `httpd.conf (Apache/conf)` and uncomment `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`, ah, don't forget to restart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `mod_rewrite` directive in your `httpd.conf`

It's usually just commented out on a fresh install.